# How to check internet connection before app starts and while it is running?

Tags: android

I found a lot of answer about this but unable to implement those also.
I want to implement this code here but not able to do so.

This code I found on google documentation.

```
ConnectivityManager cm =
           (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

  NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
  boolean isConnected = activeNetwork != null &&
                  activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
```

https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html#DetermineConnection

```
public class JSONfunctions {

public static JSONObject getJSONfromURL(String url) {
    InputStream is = null;
    String result = "";
    JSONObject jArray = null;

    // Download JSON data from URL
    try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
    }

    // Convert response to string
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        if (is != null) {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        }
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        if (reader != null) {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line).append("\n");
            }
        }
        if (is != null) {
            is.close();
        }
        result = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    try {

        jArray = new JSONObject(result);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    return jArray;
}
```

}

Comment: from where you call `getJSONfromURL` method before you check for connectivity and is its get true than after you call this method

Comment: I have a lot of activity which cal this method so I have to add this code in every class @AbhishekPatel

Comment: you just make a method for internet connectivity and call this from where you want

Comment: okay..Wil do this @AbhishekPatel

Comment: please show my answer @user3507451

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

Update the solution for internet checking. What works for me now is this

```
fun isNetworkAvailable(context: Context?): Boolean {
    if (context == null) return false

    val connectivityManager =
        context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        val capabilities =
            connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(connectivityManager.activeNetwork)
        return capabilities != null &&
                (capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR) ||
                        capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI) ||
                        capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_ETHERNET))
    } else {
        try {
            val activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.activeNetworkInfo
            return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected
        } catch (ignored: Exception) {
        }
    }

    return false
}
```

**OLD:**

Simple function to check the internet connection

```
protected boolean isOnline() {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

and in your AndroidManifest.xml you should add the permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: I put this method in my activity and now I call my  " new DownloadJSON().execute();".So now can u tell me how to use it I did it like this"    if (isOnline()== true) {
            new DownloadJSON().execute();
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Not Connected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }"   @SecretCoder

Comment: Ok thanks...@Secreat Coder  So does this code  work if network internet connectivity lost in the middle of the app

Comment: this code will only check before you use internet connection of your app, if you want to real time check your internet connection then you can implement a broadcast receiver for that

Answer (score 0):

```
public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (activeNetwork != null) {
        if (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
            return true;
        } else if (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 protected boolean isNetworkAvilable() {
        boolean isNetworkAvilable = false;
        ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo info = manager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (info != null && info.isAvailable() && info.isConnected()) {
            isNetworkAvilable = true;
        }
        return isNetworkAvilable;
    }


   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: Thanks @Rohit Heera....I already accepted the answer.All the answers are correct..I cannot upvote..but ur answer due to my less reputation

Comment: Its ok .This is not about voting its about your help. If you get your answer that is must for me Thanks

Answer (score 0):

like this you can make this method in your common file for your project

```
 public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context ctx) {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) ctx
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()
            && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()
            && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

and use like

```
if(commonfile.isNetworkAvilable(pass your context here))
{
  //call your method
}
```

and don't forgot to add permission for Internet in your manifeast

Comment: I added the permission and did like this  "   if(isNetworkAvilable())
        {
            new DownloadJSON().execute();
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Not Connected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    And switch off theinternet but did not see my toast and app get crashed  @Abhishek Patel

Comment: Thank you @Abhishek Patel  I don't have enough reputation to upvote u

Comment: always wc @user3507451. NP

Comment: getSystemservice cannot be used with static reference @AbhishekPatel

Answer (score 0):

what happens if your device connected to internet, but no input data? You also have to check whether you are receiving data or not. Check below code to see you are connected internet and able access data. You just need to ping a site and see if your responce back is 200.

```
 public class internetchek extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {

 public boolean connection;
 Context ctx;
 public internetchek(Context context){
  this.ctx = context;
 }
 public internetchek(){

 }
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

if(isNetworkAvailable(this.ctx))
{

 Log.d("NetworkAvailable","TRUE");
    if(connectGoogle())
    {

        Log.d("GooglePing","TRUE");
        connection=true;
    }
    else
    {

        Log.d("GooglePing","FALSE");
        connection=false;
    }
 }
 else {

    connection=false;
 }


 return null;
 }

 @Override
 protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
   super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
 }

 public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {
   ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)        context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
   NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
   if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected()) {
    return true;
   }
   return false;
  }

  public static boolean connectGoogle() {
    try {
     HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) (new     URL("http://www.google.com").openConnection());
    urlc.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Test");
    urlc.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
    urlc.setConnectTimeout(10000);
    urlc.connect();
    return (urlc.getResponseCode() == 200);

  } catch (IOException e) {

     Log.d("GooglePing","IOEXCEPTION");
     e.printStackTrace();
     return false;
  }
}
```

UPDATE: If you want to use it for other classes you can do this..make sure you put below code in AsyncTask or background running thread.

```
       if(internetchek.isNetworkAvailable(this.ctx)||internetchek.connectGoogle())
 {

 //Do your stuff here. when you have internet access 

 }
```

Comment: So I created this class and now how can I implement this in my others class which uses my JsonFunction class as mention above.@sandesh

Comment: Updated my answer for using in other classes. However if you just want to check internet connection you just need to execute the asyctask(internetchek).