# I want to check the Internet connection

Tags: android, android-internet

I try code

```
ConnectivityManager cm =
        (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
boolean isConnected = activeNetwork != null &&
                      activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
```

It checks WiFi or Mobile network open and close only. But I want to check with Internet access. Such as open WiFi, but can connect the Internet.

Comment: Check my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37430738/how-to-check-internet-connection-before-app-starts-and-while-it-is-running/37431259#37431259

Comment: Make a test http request to a website?

Answer (score 1):

I use a ping in Google to check the if the user have real internet connection, just be careful if your user is in China or any other country which Google is blocked.

```
public boolean isOnline() {

    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    try {

        Process ipProcess = runtime.exec("/system/bin/ping -c 1 8.8.8.8");
        int     exitValue = ipProcess.waitFor();
        return (exitValue == 0);

    } catch (IOException e)          { e.printStackTrace(); } 
      catch (InterruptedException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

    return false;
}
```